# Creating a table by combining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to merge about 5 tables, all with different columns i Postgres. Only 2-3 columns are common acrros them, and rest are not.

Table 1 - col A, col B, col C, col D

Table 2 - col X, col Y, col C, col D

Lets say both the tables have 1 row each. I am looking for an output table with 2 rows, 1 from each table above (Not a join):

Result Table: col A, col B, col C, col D, col X, col Y

Any pointers on what would be a good way to do it?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `union all`:

```
select a, b, c, d, null as x, null as  y
from table1
union all
select null, null, c, d, x, y
from table2;
```

You can generalize this to more tables and columns.  The key is ordering the columns in the `select`, so they go into the right output column.